# Is there a non-literal meaning to "L'arbre est plus grand que la fleur"

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction

I am starting with the most basic of French and this is one of the exercise questions in my book.

"L'arbre est plus grand que la fleur"

A direct translation on Google tells me that "The shaft is greater than the flower."

Does l'arbre in this case refer to 'tree' and does the sentence mean that the tree is grander (visual) or bigger (physical) than the flower?

I don't know if my question is weird or silly but I really do appreciate your help!

**Edit: I could and should have phrased my question better. And used a real dictionary.**

My response to a helpful user, that might shed light on my confusion when trying to understand the sentence in question:

"Thank you for pointing out - I will ask better questions in future. :) Just to clarify a little, on hindsight since "grand" means 'magnificent' or 'important' in English, I perhaps convoluted my understanding of the simple sentence. I was wondering if there was a deeper meaning to the sentence to native speakers. i.e. The flower although beautiful, is not at magnificent as the tree that gives it life. Thanks once again.

Comment: Google translation is not good. Use a dictionary.  [arbre](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/arbre) [grand](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/grand).

Comment: [I tried to google translate it](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/L%27arbre%20est%20plus%20grand%20que%20la%20fleur), and the result was "The tree is larger than the flower", which is way better than the translation you obtained. Does Google translate translates differently depending on the country you're in?

Comment: @krabcakes  Welcome to Stack Exchange! Your question here basically falls short because you didn't really look these words up in decent dictionaries. Google Translate is notoriously unreliable, unfortunately. If you use a dictionary, the sentence is easy to translate to "The tree is bigger (*plus grand* = "more big" = bigger) than the flower."  Try to look things up before asking here; you'll get a better response.

Comment: In French, the word SHAFT like for a machine, is arbre!

Comment: @Aerovistae Thank you for pointing out - I will ask better questions in future. :) Just to clarify a little, on hindsight since "grand" means 'magnificent' or 'important' in English, I perhaps convoluted my understanding of the simple sentence. I was wondering if there was a deeper meaning to the sentence to native speakers. i.e. The flower although beautiful, is not at magnificent as the tree that gives it life. Thanks once again.

Comment: @ThomasFrancois I googled it on my iPhone initially when I got shaft. I just googled it on my laptop and got the same result as yours. Weird huh.

Comment: @krabcakes lol there's also no need to edit apologies into your question. you're not being judged before a panel. it's just stuff to keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3):

This is to my knowledge an incorrect translation. Google Translate is highly unreliable.

The correct translation is: "The tree is taller than the flower."

The word *grand* could either mean *taller* or *bigger* in either a non-physical or a physical way. It really depends on the sentence and in this particular case both could work. But I think they meant big as in tall, in a physical sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: I'm not new to stack exchange. I'm new to the French part though. Thanks, had I knew my first language had its own sub I would of come earlier.

Comment: Oh, right you are. When I see people with 1 reputation I assume they are new. This is the first time out of perhaps 50 that it has been a false assumption. By the way, it's "would *have* come earlier" :)

Comment: Well I'm 1 in 50. Praise the luck XD. I'm native French lol.